# Finding small root of $y = ax + b$ over a finite field

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic, roots, finite-fields, integer-lattices

Take $a, b \in \mathbb Z / p\mathbb Z$, $p$ being a large prime number.

Suppose there exists a small root $(x, y)$, $x = O(\sqrt p)$ and $y = O(\sqrt p)$ to the equation $y = ax + b \mod p$.

How could one find this root?

I was thinking about using a lattice reduction algorithm, for instance using the fact that

$$1 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ -b \\ 1\end{pmatrix} + x \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -a \\ 0\end{pmatrix} + \lambda \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ q \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$ for some $\lambda$, because the resulting vector is quite small, but it does not seem to be enough. And because of the presence of $b$, I could not use only two dimensions.

Comment: Is $p$ a prime?

Comment: @BrianTung Yes, $p$ is a prime. I edited the question.

Comment: Also, $x$ and $y$ are values, not functions. What do you mean that they are $O(\sqrt{p})$? Do you mean that they are approximately equal to $\sqrt{p}$, or that they are less than $\sqrt{p}$, or what?

Comment: @BrianTung I mean that they are bounded above by a constant time $p$ for any instance of this problem, when $p$ is large enough. I am pretty confident this notation is correct, but I might be wrong.

Comment: It means that if $x$ and $y$ are considered as functions of $p$, then there exists some $k$ such that $x(p), y(p) < k\sqrt{p}$. If you mean simply that $x, y < \sqrt{p}$, I would say that.

Comment: @BrianTung Yes, I mean exactly what you said. They can be greater than $\sqrt p$. For some constant $c$, they are bounded above by $c \sqrt p$.

Comment: Your question is a special case of [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/70693/small-solutions-to-modular-arithmetic-linear-congruence) question

Comment: @Erik indeed, huge thanks!